# HttpAdapter to JavaServlet commnication

Tags: servlets, ibm-mobilefirst

Initially we had the application server as a separate one. The communication to the Application Server from worklight servers using adapters. But currently we are moving the Application Server code to the Worklight's Server folder. We are able to call the java class (Simple java class not servlets) using HTTPAdapter. But it is difficult to communicate with the servlet (which is included in the server folder) using HTTPAdapter. Plese provide any solution?

Comment: You should give more details and possibly an example of what you are trying to do and what you still cannot do. Currently, your question is rather unclear.

Comment: Currently the worklightapplication and tomcat server are two different applications in different machines;and we are using HTTPAdapter for the communication between worklightapplication to the tomcat server.We have to run the J2EE application running in tomcat server and the hybrid application within the same worklight server.To achieve this we include the applicationserver code within the server folder which is included within the hybrid application.Is it possible to call the servlet from the application which is placed within the same hybrid application’s server folder using HTTPAdapter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have put some servlet classes in your Worklight server folder. As they are Java classes they are now visible to your adapters. However servlets to be true servlets must be deployed to a JEE servlet engine, with appropriate configuration. You can deploy Servlets (in a WAR file of their own) as a separate JEE application on the same server as Worklight, but you cannot package them **inside** Worklight itself.

edited in response to your clarification:

You want to consolidate your servlet application, which is providing data accessed via the worklight adapter onto the same server instance as the worklight server. The Worklight Server is actually a JEE application deployed to one of the supported JEE servers, usually WebSphere Liberty which is supplied with Worklight, and the Worklight Server is in fact packaged as a WAR file. Your Data Provider servlet will also be packaged as a WAR file, all you need to do is deploy that WAR to the Liberty server you are currently using for worklight.

If you are doing this is development in Worklight Studio you can find the relevent folders by looking under "Worklight Development Server". You can drop the WAR into the apps folder and if necessary edit the server.xml to add any extra configuration:

```
  WorklightServerConfig/servers/worklight/server.xml
```

See: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSCKBL_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/twlp_dep_war.html

a second edit to try to explain again.

The Worklight Project represents your application, when you deploy to the Worklight Server a WAR file is created let's call this MyApp.WAR, that can be deployed to a WebSphere Application Server, inside Worklight Studio you are automatically given a WebSphere Liberty Profile. That Liberty Profile's configuration can be seen in the Project Worklight Development Server. Key Idea here you have one App Server that Liberty Profile, and you deploy the MyApp.WAR file to create what we usually call the Worklight server, it's the MyApp.WaR that is serving your Worklight console. That WAR file is derived from the contents of your project's **server** folder, this folder's name is a little misleading it's not the "server" itself it's your project-specific WAR information.

Now in addition you want to run a Servlet you already have packaged as a WAR file, let's call this Data.WAR. The key point is that you need to run Data.WAR on the Worklight Developmennt Server, the Liberty Profile. You are not including this DATA.WAR file into your project's server folder, that would effectively put DATA.war inside MyApp.WAR. Instead all you need to do is put Data.WAR in the Worklight Developmennt Server's apps folder and adjust the server.xml.

So: Step 1. Get Data.WAR running in the Development Server. Verify that from a browser you can call your expected servlet. Note the URL that works. Do not make any attempt to use your adapter until you have verified this.

Step 2. Adjust you adapter to call that URL.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.When i follow this procedure a new folder gets created and the application server project get created and the and the communication is possible. My question is is it possible to call the servlet which is included within the server folder, resides within the hybrid application.

Comment: In my answer I tried to explain: a servlet can only be called AS A SERLVET when it runs in a servlet engine. In the body of a hybrid application it is just a set of java classes. Worklight itself is a JEE application, you should not be trying to add your own servlet code to Worklight. Perhaps you should explain what you are hoping to achieve by your approach, WHY you see a benefit in this co-packaging, maybe we can suggest something.

Comment: Currently the worklightapplication and tomcat server are two different applications in different machines;and we are using HTTPAdapter for the communication between worklightapplication to the tomcat server.We have to run the J2EE application running in tomcat server and the hybrid application within the same worklight server.To achieve this we include the applicationserver code within the server folder which is included within the hybrid application.Is it possible to call the servlet from the application which is placed within the same hybrid application’s server folder using HTTPAdapter?

Comment: I've adjusted my answer. Yes you can achieve what you want.

Comment: I have imported the servlet war file in to the server folder inside the worklight application,and try to invoke the procedure using HTTPAdapter.got a response as 
{
"isSuccessful": true,
   "responseHeaders": {
      "Content-Language": "en-US",
      "Date": "Tue, 19 Aug 2014 08:47:51 GMT",
      "Location": "http:\/\/192.168.1.70:8080\/AppServer\/?userName=abcdef&passWord=abcdef&origin=Login",
      "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
      "X-Powered-By": "Servlet\/3.0"
   },
   "responseTime": 3,
   "statusCode": 302,
   "statusReason": "Found",
   "totalTime": 3
}
how can I resolve it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you have done. If you really mean the server folder inside the Worklight project then this is wrong. This is not what I have told you to do. I will make one more attempt to explain the procedure I have in mind. Please read my updated answer.

Comment: I made the changes as you suggested. Now i have the servlet application successfully deployed in the Worklight Server. I can access the servlet through a web server and i do get the response from it. But when i use the HTTP Adapter to do the same communication, and the invoke procedure gives and HTML response, with body content saying "Context root not found". But by providing the same context root i can get to the Servlet through a browser.

Comment: Double check your adapter configuration. Make sure that host and port in XML and URL in javascript are correct, note that in javascript you do not specify host and port, so it's a partial URL. I'm 100% sure that this pattern will work, do it myself many, many times. Worst case open a new question showing the URL that works in browser and the adapter xml and code.